# Angularjs conditional binding

Tags: angularjs

I have used angular's ng-model for quite some time which demonstrates two way data binding. What i want to accomplish is to bind only an input field to a model only if there are changes.

If I have

```
<input value="Hello world">
```

I want the value to be propagated to a model variable only if there are changes made to the value.

Comment: please show us what you have instead of just asking for a solution

Comment: My purpose for this is for update forms. I have an object whose properties are to be updated. Now I dont want to send the same object to the server with the same properties when i update just one field. I accomplish this by making the original objects attribute values as placeholders and I bind the fields via ng-model of a new object that will be sent to the server. It works fine but the problem is the user will have to type again from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer would depend on event you want to use to update model.

Assuming you are wanting an "edit form " but don't want the master model to update live you can make a copy of the model and extend the master on "save"

Starting data:

```
$scope.item ={age: 25, name: 'Foo Bar'};
$scope.editItem = angular.copy($scope.item);
```

HTML

```
<input ng-model="editItem.age">
<button ng-click="updateItem()">Update</button>
```

Update function:

```
$scope.updateItem = function (){
  $http.put(url, $scope.editItem).success(function(resp){
     // merge data
     angular.extend( $scope.item, $scope.editItem);
  });
}
```

You could also do something similar using `ng-change`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with using of additional variable and $watch. Example:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="searchText">
```

And in controller

```
$scope.$watch('searchText', function() {
    $scope.filterText = $scope.searchText;
});
```

So $scope.filterText will be changed to $scope.searchText value if any changes in input

Comment: It can work but how about say I have ten fields. Then I have to make ten watches?

Comment: You can use $scope.$watchCollection('[input.firstValue, input,secondValue]' in a case if it is ok to change all values after change one of them. If not, you’ll have to check new and old values for all of them inside $watchCollection what seems to me not easier than using of $watch for each variable separately